# 16.04 doesn't work at all after update

Tags: 16.04

When I use 16.04 Xenial Xerus from my live CD there is no problem at all but when I install it, no matter if I use the 32 or the 64 bits version, my mouse pointer stops moving after I load the X server. Until about 3 weeks ago the brandnew release 16.04 worked perfectly but after one of the last updates the problem keeps appearing consequently, apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-broken doen't help.

My CPU: Intel Core I5

RAM: 8GB

Mainboard: ASUS H97 Pro

Answer (score 0):

If you your keyboard still functions properly then do this and it may restore your mouse:

```
Ctrl + Alt + F1
```

This will get you into TTY where you need to login

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

This will install all input devices.

```
sudo reboot
```

After reboot check to see if mouse function has returned!